# how to grab the latest release from GitHub with JitPack?

Tags: java, git, github, gradle, jitpack

Can JitPack be configured just to grab the latest release?  Or, do I need to create releases manually?

GitHub has a [simple process](https://help.github.com/articles/linking-to-releases/) to get the latest:

```
On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.

Releases tabUnder your repository name, click Releases.

Latest release tag

Right click on Latest Release and copy the URL to share it. 

The suffix of this URL is always /releases/latest.
```

in the context of learning how [git, JitPack and GitHub relate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939794/github-releases-in-relation-to-branching-as-used-by-jitpack) to each other, so that I can pull in an updated artifact from JitPack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No [Jitpack needs a Release tag, commit hash or `-SNAPSHOT`](https://jitpack.io/docs/#building) (to grab the latest sources of a branch).

That means you need to create at least a tag (and use for instance [`allegro/axion-release-plugin`](https://github.com/allegro/axion-release-plugin) to automate the creation of a GitHub release.

You [can query the latest build](https://jitpack.io/docs/API/#latest-build), but Jitpack needs a fixed reference in order to have a repeatable build.